# MySql Get the "best" row in each group, by selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB with 5000 rows which contains people, where they have data and their results, something like this:

```
Table_A
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| Name | team  |r_id | result |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| Jhon | A     | 1   | 12.45  |
| Mike | C     | 1   | 12.42  |
| Bob  | C     | 1   | 13.02  |
| ...  | ...   | ... | ...    |
| Alan | F     | 1   | 12.53  |
| ...  | ...   | ... | ...    |
| Mac  | A     | 2   | 5.24   |
| Josh | B     | 2   | 3.56   |
| Alan | F     | 2   | 4.12   |
| ...  | ...   | ... | ...    |
| Nic  | D     | 197 | 6.28   |
| Eli  | E     | 197 | 7.21   |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
```

In addition there is another table, the rid column is an intermediary to the param1 (has to be).

```
Table_B
+-----+--------+----------+
|r_id | param1 | fooData  |
+-----+--------+----------+
|   1 |      1 | A        |
|   2 |      3 | B        |
|   3 |      4 | A        |      two r_id set can have the same param1
|   4 |      4 | B        |
|   5 |      2 | C        |
|   6 |      3 | A        |
|   7 |      1 | B        |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

I need return the best of each group with a "selection".

For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON a.r_id = b.r_id
ORDER BY IF(b.fooData="A",CAST(result AS DECIMAL(4,3)),myCastFunction(result)) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

That function, order the people inside each group with a given for a given **param1**, I want the first row always, by each group, all together and a good performance obviously.

```
+--------------+------+-------+--------+
| group_param1 | Name | team  | result |
+--------------+------+-------+--------+
| 1            | Mike | C     | 12.42  |
| 3            | Josh | B     | 3.56   |
| ...          | ...  | ...   | ...    |
| 194          | Nic  | D     | 6.28   |
+--------------+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I see a list of requirements, but you have not described your problem, if any.

Comment: Please be more specific on what's the logic for deriving the output, so that it can be translated into syntactical solution. Refer [help on creating example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried to build a query? Show it!

Comment: Your data set and your result set don't correspond. somedata seems irrelevant to this problem. `group` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  `Name` VARCHAR(4),
  `team` VARCHAR(1),
  `r_id` INTEGER,
  `result` FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO table_a
  (`Name`, `team`, `r_id`, `result`)
VALUES
  ('Jhon', 'A', '1', '12.45'),
  ('Mike', 'C', '1', '12.42'),
  ('Bob', 'C', '1', '13.02'),
  ('Alan', 'F', '1', '12.53'),
  ('Mac', 'A', '2', '5.24'),
  ('Josh', 'B', '2', '3.56'),
  ('Alan', 'F', '2', '4.12'),
  ('Nic', 'D', '197', '6.28'),
  ('Eli', 'E', '197', '7.21');



CREATE TABLE table_b (
  `r_id` INTEGER,
  `param1` INTEGER,
  `fooData` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table_b
  (`r_id`, `param1`, `fooData`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'A'),
  ('2', '3', 'B'),
  ('3', '4', 'A'),
  ('4', '4', 'B'),
  ('5', '2', 'C'),
  ('6', '3', 'A'),
  ('7', '1', 'B');
```

---

**Original Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.r_id = b.r_id
ORDER BY IF(b.fooData="A",CAST(result AS DECIMAL(4,3)),SIN(result)) ASC
LIMIT 1;

| Name | team | r_id | result | r_id | param1 | fooData |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ------- |
| Mac  | A    | 2    | 5.24   | 2    | 3      | B       |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM (
  SELECT a.*,
         b.param1,
         (
           @rn := IF(b.param1 = @g, @rn + 1, IF(@g := b.param1, 1, 1) )
         ) AS rn
  FROM table_a a 
  JOIN table_b b ON a.r_id = b.r_id 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @g := '', @rn := 0
  ) params
  ORDER BY b.param1, IF(b.fooData="A",CAST(result AS DECIMAL(4,3)),SIN(result)) ASC
) ab
WHERE rn = 1;

| Name | team | r_id | result | param1 | rn  |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ------ | ------ | --- |
| Jhon | A    | 1    | 12.45  | 1      | 1   |
| Mac  | A    | 2    | 5.24   | 3      | 1   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mxKiheAPKj2EUeYUz8Pzzk/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need a join to identify the groups.  Then you need some method to choose the first row.  I would go with variables:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.*, b.grp,
             (@rn := if(b.grp = @g, @rn + 1,
                        if(b.grp := @g, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table_a a join
           table_b b
           on a.r_id = b.r_id cross join
           (select @g := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by b.grp, a.result
     ) ab
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mysql doesn't support partitioning, the easiest way is probably to use subselect from `table_a`:

```
select a.* from
    (select distinc group from table_b) grp
    inner join table_a a
        on a.r_id in (select b.r_id from table_b b where b.group = grp.group) and
        result = (
            select min(result) from table_a ai where
                ai.r_id in (select b.r_id from table_b b where b.group = grp.group)
        )
```